# How can i get response from fetch API React Native

Tags: json, web-services, reactjs, react-native

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "result":{  
      "sessionName":"2a7777703f6f219d"
      "userId":"19x1"
      "version":"0.22"
   }
};
```

---

```
fetch('https://myapi/api', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'xxxx1',
    secondParam: 'xxxx1',
  })
})
```

How can i get response from fetch API React Native (Post method)

I need to console.log to see sessionName in result (I think it's response.result.sessionName)

But I don't know how to get it from fetch.

Where is response from fetch like a get method

---

Here's  Get method from facebook (it's have response)

```
 function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson.movies;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch. It's just `fetch(uri, opts).then(response => { } )`, the same syntax as `GET`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the same as GET method:

```
fetch('https://myapi/api', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'xxxx1',
    secondParam: 'xxxx1',
  })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);// your JSON response is here
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thank You . I try it and get some error Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: what is the error? Why this has the ";" semicolon here ^^? [fetch('devsma.idefenc.com/vtdev/webservice.php';, {...]
Could you please paste here the errors, thanks

Comment: it's Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: So does it mean that the JSON you posted is invalid? could you please provide more clues, thanks

Comment: This is my header  'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',  //                                                               And My JSON  {  "success":true,
 "result":
 {
 "sessionName":"6668880faf5944446e2zzfb",
 "userId":"9x1",
 "version":"0.22",
 "vtigerVersion":"6.5.0"
 }
}

Comment: ^^ That is the returned JSON, or the JSON you posted?

Comment: That is return of JSON from my posted
I don't know What's wrong this JSON

Comment: I think the JSON you posted had problem, not the returned one! could you send here your full code ?